# How to get localized description string of file size in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

Following is my code:

```
- (NSString *)fileSizeDescriptionForFileAtPath:(NSString *)filePath {

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *fileDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath
                                                                                    error: &error];
    NSNumber *size = [fileDictionary objectForKey:NSFileSize];

    NSString *desc = [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:size.longLongValue
                                         countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile];

return desc;
}
```

Is this code will correctly format the file size for any localization?

I found no reference in `NSByteCountFormatter` documentation that formatted strings are localized.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: So create a `NSByteCountFormatter`, set it to `NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile` , set the system locale to something different, and try it. The docs on the `NSByteCountFormatter ` do mention that certain settings may not be valid for certain locales, which at least *implies* that it supports locales. However, `NSByteCountFormatter` doesn't seem to have a locale property, which is surprising.

Comment: BTW, before reading your post I hadn't heard of `NSByteCountFormatter` before. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. (voted.)

Comment: Before posting questions like this, you need to try it yourself. It would have been much faster than posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried the above code with several locales and the result looks perfectly localized.